# When an orthonormal set is a basis (proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces

Problem:

> Let $B$  an orthonormal set in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Show that $B$ is a basis (i.e $\overline{span(B)} = \mathcal{H})$ if and only if $B^\perp = \{0\}$.

My attempt:
 
$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $B$ is a basis and let $x\in B^\perp$. There exists then a finite linear combination of elements $e_i$ in $B$ such that for a given $\varepsilon > 0$
$$ ||x-\sum_{i=1}^n c_ie_i || < \varepsilon$$
for some scalars $c_i$. This inequallity reaches its minimum when 
$$ ||x-\sum_{i=1}^n <x,e_i>e_i || \le ||x-\sum_{i=1}^n c_ie_i ||  < \varepsilon $$
but since $x \in B^\perp$ this leads to $||x|| < \varepsilon$ and then $x = 0$.
$(\Leftarrow)$ Since 
$$ (span(B)^\perp)^\perp = \overline{span(B)}$$
we have $\overline{span(B)} = \{0\}^\perp = \mathcal{H}$
Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: What do the $x_i$s refer to? Are they different from the $e_i$s?

Comment: @TheoBendit yes, thanks for looking at it. Just fixed

Comment: A basis for a vector space has two properties- the vectors are independent and they span the space.  An orthogonal set of vectors is necessarily independent so given that a set of vector is orthogonal it s only necessary to show that it spans the space.

Comment: @user247327 according to my definitions, that's only true for a Hamel basis. In general a set $B$ is a basis if $\overline{span(B)} = H$. Sorry for not making clear in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the changes, this looks good now. I do think some small tweaks to the wording could make this even clearer.

I think it's worth rewording

> This inequality reaches its minimum when 
>   $$ \left\|x-\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,e_i \rangle e_i \right\| \le \left\|x-\sum_{i=1}^n c_ie_i \right\| < \varepsilon.$$

Instead, you might want to say,

> Note that the quantity
>   $$\left\|x-\sum_{i=1}^n d_ie_i \right\|$$
>   reaches its minimum when $d_i = \langle x, e_i \rangle$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Therefore,
>   $$ \left\|x-\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,e_i \rangle e_i \right\| \le \left\|x-\sum_{i=1}^n c_ie_i \right\| < \varepsilon.$$

You may also want to reference a theorem for this fact!

The other thing I would rewords is this:

> ...since $x \in B^\perp$ this leads to $\|x\| < \varepsilon$ and then $x = 0$.

I would put it like this:

> ...since $x \in B^\perp$ this leads to $\|x\| < \varepsilon$. As $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, we have $x = 0$.

Other than that, I think it's perfectly clear.